# Why don't camera mesh appear in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have two cameras and for each I've associated a Mesh Filter and Mesh Renderer (which are just red and green cubes. I notice that in the Scene view I can see one cameras position from the other camera. But when I actually play the scene the camera I'm looking through cannot see the cube of the other camera?

[image]

EDIT: Adding some clarity I hope.
When I click the play symbol.
When I switch to the green camera it cannot see the red camera.
When I switch to the red camera it cannot see the green camera.
Even though both cameras has a mesh attached to them which appears both in the Scene and Game previews (screenshot above).

Comment: Quite unclear what you are asking .. you are looking through the camera with the green cube and as far as I can tell you pretty much **can** se the other (red) cube in the GameView very well .. Note that when you have multiple Cameras in the same scene then what do you expect to happen? There is only one display so they just render their images on top of each other and you will only see the last one .. except you actually want to have multiple image in image renderings and have configured the clear flags and rendered layers of your cameras accordingly ... What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: It disappears as soon as I hit play.

Answer (score 3):

The camera at the position of the green cube cannot see the green cube because it is inside the cube and the standard material uses backface culling, which means that only the fronts of the faces of the mesh are drawn and not their backs. And the standard Unity cube has all its faces facing outwards.

Also, I assume the cube would have been clipped regardless, since it's too close, under the near clipping distance of the camera. So anything outside the camera frustum will not be drawn.